# Why does webservice toss null pointer in Xamarin Forms

Tags: web-services, xamarin.forms

I have a Xamarin Forms application, I've added a WCF Web Service, that I'm using in another project. I can create a Soap client for this webservice, with one of the provided endpoints. When I try to access any method on this client it tosses a null pointer without offering any details about the exception.

Has anyone had a similar problem? Are there some permission issues with using Xamarin Forms this way?

```
            HelloWorldResponse res = null; 
            try { 
                ServiceReference1.UserServicesSoapClient client = new 
UserServicesSoapClient(UserServicesSoapClient.EndpointConfiguration.UserServicesSoap12); 
                HelloWorldRequest req = new HelloWorldRequest(); 
                res = await client.HelloWorldAsync(req); 
            } catch(Exception ex) { 
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString()); 
            } 
            return res;
```

Thanks,

Comment: there is no way we can answer this with the information provided.  Have you tried catching the exception?  There is no stack trace of exception detail?

Comment: code:            HelloWorldResponse res = null;
            try
            {
                ServiceReference1.UserServicesSoapClient client = new UserServicesSoapClient(UserServicesSoapClient.EndpointConfiguration.UserServicesSoap12);

                HelloWorldRequest req = new HelloWorldRequest();
                res = await client.HelloWorldAsync(req);
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            }
            return res;

Comment: Sorry about the formatting. There is no stack trace with the exception, just that it occurred in the HelloWorldAsync call.

Comment: please [edit] your question, do not stuff code into a comment.  The `ex` object does not contain a stack trace or any other useful information?

Comment: have you tried stepping through the actual `UserServicesSoapClient` code to see where the exception occurs?

Comment: Yes I have stepped through the code as far as I can.

Comment: so what line causes the exception?  have you tried wrapping that specific line in a try/catch?  Or examined it to determine which element is null?

Comment: Its the client.HellowordAsync call that causes the null pointer exception and it does not show which element is null.

Comment: why can't you debug `UserServicesSoapClient`?  Isn't that code generated and included as part of your client?